# Import UV Mapping on mesh

Tags: coordinates

i would like to import a uv mapping coordinate to a mesh, but the code didn't work, cause there is an error on Blender 3.3:
File "C:\Users\Marku\Desktop\Blender Plugin\uvw.blend\Text.001", line 24, in 
KeyError: 40

````
import bpy

me = bpy.context.object.data

uv_tex = me.uv_layers.new()
uv_layer = me.uv_layers[-1].data

vert_loops = {}
for l in me.loops:
    vert_loops.setdefault(l.vertex_index, []).append(l.index)
    
vert_uvs = [(0.12384849786758423, 0.5494712591171265),(0.12384811043739319, 0.0034536700695753098),(0.24882176518440247, 0.0034535210579633713),(0.2488219141960144, 0.5494712591171265),(0.2488219141960144, 0.5494712591171265),(0.24882176518440247, 0.0034535210579633713),(0.3737952411174774, 0.0034535210579633713),
(0.3737952709197998, 0.5494711399078369),(0.3737952709197998, 0.5494711399078369),(0.3737952411174774, 0.0034535210579633713),(0.49876871705055237, 0.0034535210579633713),(0.49876868724823, 0.5494711399078369),(0.49876868724823, 0.5494711399078369),(0.49876871705055237, 0.0034535210579633713),(0.6237421631813049, 0.0034536700695753098),(0.6237420439720154, 0.5494711399078369),(0.6237420439720154, 0.5494711399078369),(0.6237421631813049, 0.0034536700695753098),(0.7487156987190247, 0.0034536700695753098),(0.7487152814865112, 0.5494711399078369),(0.7487152814865112, 0.5494711399078369),(0.7487156987190247, 0.0034536700695753098),
(0.8736891150474548, 0.003453729674220085),(0.8736886978149414, 0.5494712591171265),(0.8736886978149414, 0.5494712591171265),(0.8736891150474548, 0.003453729674220085),(0.998662531375885, 0.003453848883509636),(0.998661994934082, 0.5494712591171265),(-0.0011249184608459473, 0.549471378326416),(-0.001125425100326538, 0.0034536700695753098),(0.12384811043739319, 0.0034536700695753098),(0.12384849786758423, 0.5494712591171265),(0.8936221599578857, 0.5762031078338623),(0.7818735837936401, 0.5759849548339844),(0.7706657648086548, 0.5497416257858276),(0.9041361808776855, 0.5496834516525269),(0.7818735837936401, 0.5759849548339844),(0.7023438215255737, 0.6543290615081787),(0.6758830547332764, 0.6436777114868164),(0.7706657648086548, 0.5497416257858276),(0.7023438215255737, 0.6543290615081787),
(0.7018402218818665, 0.7655781507492065),(0.6756812334060669, 0.7768880128860474),(0.6758830547332764, 0.6436777114868164),(0.7018402218818665, 0.7655781507492065),(0.7807475328445435, 0.8440647125244141),(0.7702689170837402, 0.8705624341964722),(0.6756812334060669, 0.7768880128860474),(0.7807475328445435, 0.8440647125244141),(0.8924964666366577, 0.8443202972412109),(0.9036567211151123, 0.8705623149871826),(0.7702689170837402, 0.8705624341964722),(0.8924964666366577, 0.8443202972412109),(0.9721583127975464, 0.766228437423706),(0.9986177682876587, 0.7768851518630981),(0.9036567211151123, 0.8705623149871826),(0.9721583127975464, 0.766228437423706),(0.9724907875061035, 0.6549867391586304),
(0.9986627101898193, 0.6436810493469238),(0.9986177682876587, 0.7768851518630981),(0.9724907875061035, 0.6549867391586304),(0.8936221599578857, 0.5762031078338623),(0.9041361808776855, 0.5496834516525269),(0.9986627101898193, 0.6436810493469238),(0.8842759132385254, 0.5983641147613525),(0.7908287048339844, 0.5983297824859619),(0.7818735837936401, 0.5759849548339844),(0.8936221599578857, 0.5762031078338623),(0.7908287048339844, 0.5983297824859619),(0.7244090437889099, 0.6638002395629883),(0.7023438215255737, 0.6543290615081787),(0.7818735837936401, 0.5759849548339844),(0.7244090437889099, 0.6638002395629883),
(0.7240447998046875, 0.7565466165542603),(0.7018402218818665, 0.7655781507492065),(0.7023438215255737, 0.6543290615081787),(0.7240447998046875, 0.7565466165542603),(0.7900638580322266, 0.821906328201294),(0.7807475328445435, 0.8440647125244141),(0.7018402218818665, 0.7655781507492065),(0.7900638580322266, 0.821906328201294),(0.8835827112197876, 0.8219642639160156),(0.8924964666366577, 0.8443202972412109),(0.7807475328445435, 0.8440647125244141),(0.8835827112197876, 0.8219642639160156),(0.9501087665557861, 0.7567672729492188),(0.9721583127975464, 0.766228437423706),(0.8924964666366577, 0.8443202972412109),(0.9501087665557861, 0.7567672729492188),(0.9502570629119873, 0.6640243530273438),(0.9724907875061035, 0.6549867391586304),(30, 0.9721583127975464, 0.766228437423706),(39, 0.9502570629119873, 0.6640243530273438),(32, 0.8842759132385254, 0.5983641147613525),(25, 0.8936221599578857, 0.5762031078338623),(31, 0.9724907875061035, 0.6549867391586304),(15, 0.9216725826263428, 0.676622748374939),(1, 0.8729163408279419, 0.6276178359985352),(32, 0.8842759132385254, 0.5983641147613525),(39, 0.9502570629119873, 0.6640243530273438),(13, 0.9211483001708984, 0.7452778816223145),(15, 0.9216725826263428, 0.676622748374939),(39, 0.9502570629119873, 0.6640243530273438),(38, 0.9501087665557861, 0.7567672729492188),(11, 0.8711893558502197, 0.7930192947387695),
(13, 0.9211483001708984, 0.7452778816223145),(38, 0.9501087665557861, 0.7567672729492188),(37, 0.8835827112197876, 0.8219642639160156),(9, 0.801383376121521, 0.7926114797592163),(11, 0.8711893558502197, 0.7930192947387695),(37, 0.8835827112197876, 0.8219642639160156),(36, 0.7900638580322266, 0.821906328201294),(7, 0.7525244951248169, 0.7439746856689453),(9, 0.801383376121521, 0.7926114797592163),(36, 0.7900638580322266, 0.821906328201294),(35, 0.7240447998046875, 0.7565466165542603),(5, 0.753441333770752, 0.6753729581832886),(7, 0.7525244951248169, 0.7439746856689453),(35, 0.7240447998046875, 0.7565466165542603),(34, 0.7244090437889099, 0.6638002395629883),(3, 0.8032954931259155, 0.6272165775299072),(5, 0.753441333770752, 0.6753729581832886),(34, 0.7244090437889099, 0.6638002395629883),(33, 0.7908287048339844, 0.5983297824859619),(1, 0.8729163408279419, 0.6276178359985352),(3, 0.8032954931259155, 0.6272165775299072),(33, 0.7908287048339844, 0.5983297824859619),
(32, 0.8842759132385254, 0.5983641147613525)]
# with uv coords in order of vertices

for i, coord in enumerate(vert_uvs):
    # For every loop of a vertex
    for li in vert_loops[i]:
        uv_layer[li].uv = coord
```
````

Comment: Your code expects the active mesh to have at least 128 verts, but your mesh presumably has only 40.

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/importing-uv-coordinates/595872/5 i change to that code, but have now the problem, that the uv mapping don't use "mark seam" .. hm